# Which open source license has no forking

Tags: open-source

I remember reading about an open source license which did not grant permission to fork.

I don't remember its name and thought it might be easier to ask here than to go through the entire list of [OSI's approved licenses](http://opensource.openmirrors.org/licenses/alphabetical.html). Anyone knows which license I might be talking about?

Comment: There are Open-Source licenses that require you to contribute back any patches; are you perhaps thinking of those?

Comment: @MSalters, No I know a fair bit about OS licenses so I could tell it wasn't about contributing back the patches. This one was very unique.

Comment: [This answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/349/8652) says, "All libre/free/open-source licenses grant the right to fork. This is sometimes known as the “fork test” for software license. It is freedom 1 in the [Free Software Definition](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), guideline 1 in the [DFSG](https://www.debian.org/social_contract#guidelines), clause 1 in the [Open Source Definition](http://opensource.org/osd-annotated)."

Answer (score 5):

First thing which comes to my mind is CC-ND: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/

Comment: Note that this is _not_ an Open Source license by the OSI definition, and it's not on the list that you quote. The list itself is CC-licensed so the omission is not because OSI is unaware of the CC family of licenses.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you're embarking on a doomed quest here, given that item 3 of the [OSI definition of an open source license](http://www.opensource.org/docs/definition.php) seems to explicitly prohibit a clause that would prevent forking.

Answer (score 1):

By definition Open Source allow fork:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source_definition

A license that didn't allow forking isn't an Open Source license

Comment: It's defenition of FSF. You, as an author, have the right to have your own opinion of "what is open source software" and which rights you grant to the end users.

Comment: Berming specifically invoked the OSI which has a very specific definition.

Comment: The one I'm talking about was already approved by the OSI, so I know for fact that one already exists.

Comment: @Berming really surprising ! Waiting for the proof ...

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised too when I read about it. Wish I had bookmarked it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the only thing you can do is just use some trickery, like manipulate your trademark policy and the code well enough to effectively prevent a fork.

And as was mentioned, doing this in the license will technically make it no longer free software.