# Help me out choosing a software license

Tags: open-source, licensing, software-distribution

My application is reaching a pretty nice beta/alpha level and I might at some point publish it. I have not decided what software license to use in my application. The application is under construction. I bet this must be a question that every developer thinks about at some point.

My software is more like a library and here are some key factors in my case:

- It must be an open-source license.
- It must be free for developers to use as a library for their applications.
- Developers are allowed to redistribute the source code as part of their applications modified or unmodified.
- The library can be used for closed-source software.
- I want attribution/credit. A one-line credit in the software Help dialog or somewhere in about section of their website is fine. As long as it is reasonable easy for a 3rd-party to find out what library was used to produce the resulting software.
- Forking a new project out of my existing source code should not be allowed. I want people to be able to use it and even modify it, but not clone a new similar product to compete against my existing product.
- The license needs to state that I take no responsibility for any damage whatsoever.

Is there such a license? Would those requirements even fit in an open-source license?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Forking a new project out of my existing source code should not be allowed

Above is in conflict with Open Source idea (which allows/encourages forking). More info here: [Which open source license has no forking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923080/which-open-source-license-has-no-forking)

If you think that you can drop that requirement the best choice is LGPL and additional requirement that people must give you credit (you will have to define what type of attribution/credit do you want per different uses)

As James stated in previous comment:

> Forks very rarely happen

1. It is very hard to fork a (big) project
2. You can benefit more if there are forks - you can take the good ideas from the fork and leave the bad. That way the better judgement about features/code will eventually win (which is part of the idea of Open Source)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I could drop the fork requirement, but I would really want that attribution. Do you know if any of the popular OS licenses has that? And yes, I would specify how to give credit.

Comment: For attribution requirement I will suggest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses or http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find one to suit your needs here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_software_licenses

More specifically I think the GPU Lesser Public License might suit the needs of your library. Keeping in mind that like (all?) open source licenses, LGPL allows forking.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License

Answer (score 2):

> Forking a new project out of my
>   existing source code should not be
>   allowed. I want people to be able to
>   use it and even modify it, but not
>   clone a new similar product to compete
>   against my existing product.

Ummm ... This is I have never heard of in a Open Source license, and I don't know of any that have this. How would you even word it? Determining the difference between a fork and someone else who has taken your code and just added a patch would be really hard.

Can you think about this one? Forks very rarely happen, and when they do they aren't always competition. Talent, ideas and even code can flow between the forks freely.

Comment: Apart from this, I would also say look at the LGPL first.

Comment: Also, how do you tell the difference between a fork and a coder taking large chunks of your code into their LGPL (or whatever) project? I think most ppl would say any license with an anti-forking clause wasn't really open.

Comment: I've been wondering about forking and copying code a lot. It seems that I have to do some digging.

Answer (score 2):

You need to speak to a lawyer, we aren't lawyers and don't know your application.

Prevention of forking with open source licenses is complicated, as James says.

For commercial applications, you may want to look at dual licensing.

As far as I know the LGPL allows forks.